# svn delete project trunk

Tags: svn, project, trunk

How do you delete a project's trunk file folder and all contents in the file folder of the trunk.

For example my project is WHOTest and I want to delete WHOTest/trunk

Let me know thanks.

Comment: Is it cd WHOTEST and then svn del trunk ?

Answer (score 5):

You delete it like any other folder in SVN. There is nothing special with trunk folders. They're just named like that by convention.

Here's [the documentation of the `svn delete` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html)

Comment: Am new to SVN, due to my co-hort is no longer with the company due to medical LOA.  Can you perhaps give me an idea of the syntax.  Also what happens if you do the above and don't commit the changes?  How do you back out?

Comment: It's all described in the freely available SVN book. See the edit in my question. Everything must always be committed in SVN. If you don't commit, then it's only deleted in your working copy.

Comment: 'svn delete' just commits a new revision where the deleted data doesn't exist. However the data still exists in repo history and is accessible. To remove a branch (folder) completely a dump-load cycle is required with svndumpfilter filtering. See the Apache Subversion FAQ entry: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal